# Get/modify number of paid users and quotas in Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps comes with 5 free users. Let's say I buy 45 licenses for paid users, for a total of 50 user accounts. Is there any way to access the number of total licenses I have in my ADO account programmatically, either via a REST API or a client library (ideally Node.js)? I found the [User Entitlements API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) but that only gives me the total number of users in my subscription, not the total number of licenses I have available. Barring that, is there a way to set an alert so that if e.g. I have N licenses available and N-2 users, I can get notified that I'm approaching my quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [User Entitlement Summary API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlement%20summary/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1)

Specifically, you probably want to run this:

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/UserEntitlementSummary?select=accesslevels%2Clicenses
```